# How I could show data from a specific interface from iTunes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are an interface from iTunes with this type and I don't know how show this **"im:image"**:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=100/genre=1310/json

```
        export interface Entry {
          "im:image": IMImage[];
        }            
        export interface IMImage {
            label: string;
            attributes: IMImageAttributes;
        }            
        export interface IMImageAttributes {
            height: string;
        }
```

And I should render data image like this into my component:

```
  //pods is a fetched data from API REST

  pods.map((pd: Entry) => (
    <>How I should render data here? as {pd.HOW??}</>
   )
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want is to render the label in im:image array?

Comment: Yes, only one element, [0], but i don't know how show it.

Comment: Hi rafa_pe, I post an answer and it works to me. I think it will help you too~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit code to this:

```
            {pods.feed.entry.map((r) => (
                <img
                    alt='pic'
                    key={r.id.attributes['im:id']}
                    src={r['im:image'][0].label}
                />
            ))}
```

Full code would be:

```
import pods from './data.json'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(pods.feed.entry)
    }, [pods])
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            {pods.feed.entry.map((r) => (
                <img
                    alt='pic'
                    key={r.id.attributes['im:id']}
                    src={r['im:image'][0].label}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I think it can help you.

[image]